# comparing pyspark schema using dataframe.schema VS dataframe.printSchema()

Tags: apache-spark, types, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I've met a issue when trying to compare two pyspark dataframes' schema.

If I use `df1.schema == df2.schema`, it sometimes return `True` but sometimes return `False` ( I am sure the schemas are matching)

However, when I use `df1.printSchema() == df2.printSchema()`, the output is always `True`.

I know the dataType of df.schema is *pyspark.sql.types.StructType*, but why it sometimes gives the **WRONG** comparing result?  is it a bug in pyspark?

Comment: Essentially `df1.printSchema()` returns `None`, so you aren't making a meaningful comparison. It would return `True` even if your schema *didn't* match. Look at the DataFrames in question again, are they really the same? Share some data, share some code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command. This one also tells which columns are different and it is neat and clean

```
set(df1.schema).symmetric_difference(set(df2.schema))
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using `pyspark`

get `dtypes` of each dataframe which would return a `List[(column_name, data_type)]`

And Compare Like  this :

```
for idx1,el1 in enumerate(df1.dtypes):
    for idx2,el2 in enumerate(df2.dtypes):
        if idx1 == idx2:
            if el1[0] == el2[0] and el1[1] == el2[1]:
                continue
            else:
                raise ValueError("Schema Don't Match for Col {0} and {1}".format(el1[0],el2[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `df1.schema == df2.schema` doesn't give intuitive results that you want.

You can try converting the schema into a string and then doing the comparison:

`df1.schema.simpleString() == df2.schema.simpleString()`